How to open 443 port?
To know if port 443 is open on my machine which runs Ubuntu 20.04, I ran several commands (see screenshots):

When I run the command ufw status it shows me as if port 443 and 80 are both open.

On the other hand, when I run the two commands: nc -zv localhots 443 and ss -tuln | grep : 443 it shows me as if port 443 is not open. Can you please tell me the difference between these two displays and also how to open port 443 if it is closed.





actually there is a service listening on 443 port?

sudo ufw allow to any from any port 443

Please don't use screenshots of the terminal. Copy the text from the terminal and paste it directly in your question. Then use the format as code icon {_} above the edit question window to format the pasted text.

ss -tuln | grep :443 shows you nothing probably because none of your services (apache, nginx, etc) listens port 443. You need to check configuration file of service you're using to get access to your machine, probably it's listening only on port 80 (by default).
